# repeatedly using a Local Variable with `using` statement vs. repeatedly calling a Non-Local Variable ?

Tags: c#, local, using, naudio

I just got notice about using "Using", as it´s very efficient in it´s way to handle disposable objects. As it will only use them in that certain command, then it will be removed.

But i don´t know where the limit goes, as i can´t see that you Always want´s to use it, and It´s Always efficient.

So my question here is. Is this a good way to use it, or is it unnecessary or will it even hurt my performance in any way?

```
       void Sending(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        using (UdpClient udpclient = new UdpClient())
        {
       if (connect == true && MuteMic.Checked == false)
       {

               udpclient.Send(e.Buffer, e.BytesRecorded, otherPartyIP.Address.ToString(), 1500);

       }
       }
   }
```

It´s an event from NAudio, and what it does is, While WaveInEvent has any data, do this.

WaveInEvent is from an input device, so if i start recording with it (example mic), data will be available (the mic audio), and then i can do what i want with that data. In this case i am sending it over UDP.

But as you can see, i am using a local udpclient.
I don´t know if i should be using it there, or if i should have one created before so it can reuse it all the time, instead of making a new.

Hope i didn´t mess up my explanation to bad.

Comment: "i can´t see that you Always want´s to use it" -- When working with anything that implements `IDisposable` you *do* always want's to use `using`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a good way to use it, or is it unnecessary or will it even hurt my performance in any way?

You should always use it when any object implementes IDisposable. It doesn't have any negative impact on performance. All it will do is to ensure that object is properly disposed.

The using statement ensures that **Dispose** is called even if an *exception* occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler. Your code will more or less look like this for the compliler.

```
{
  UdpClient udpclient = new UdpClient();
  try
  {
   if (connect == true && MuteMic.Checked == false)
   {

           udpclient.Send(e.Buffer, e.BytesRecorded, otherPartyIP.Address.ToString(), 1500);

   }
  }
  finally
  {
    if (udpclient!= null)
      ((IDisposable)udpclient).Dispose();
  }
}
```

You can read the details of using [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: Great, that clears things out. As most of the time there is a "double edged sword" when it comes to stuff like this.

Comment: @user2587718 Glad it cleared out your mind. You can mark it as answer then.

Comment: Will do, need to wait though, timer. But i wonder a thing. Can you really Dispose an udpclient? I only see close, which i guess is something similar, but i guess it only closes the listening and doesn´t remove the actual client.

Comment: @user2587718 you can get complete details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx

Comment: I read, but don´t get it. if i need to dispose a udpclient, that method you showed doesn´t seem to work.

Comment: have you tried the updated code or  udpclient.Dispose(); Actually Dispose method is defined explicitly, therefore you have to cast it to IDisposable instance before calling dispose method like ((IDisposable)udpclient).Dispose();

Comment: @user2587718 You don't need to call it explicitly. you can simply apply using and it will take care of dispose itself.

Comment: I can´t do udpclient.Dispose, it doesn´t exist. Andi don´t think, ((IDisposable)udpclient).Dispose(); works. But i am not sure how to check if an item is disposed or not. And the scenario i am thinking of, doesn´t allow using, which is why i want to know how to properly dispose a client.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34818/discussion-between-user2587718-and-ehsan-ullah)

Answer (score 2):

As Microsoft says, generally "As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and instantiate it in a using statement."[using Statement (C# Reference) - MSDN - Microsoft](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx&ei=Yj__UdakLIm1kgX8ooDQAQ&usg=AFQjCNHVEBQOgRO-i5Hpj4KpVmkoXrLgRw&sig2=QLaC76BeV7kikuGyykUF_Q&bvm=bv.50165853,d.dGI&cad=rja). But sometimes, its a better idea to define your object as a non-local variable and call it in your local code whenever you need it rather than instantiate the object every time you want to use it and then dispose it. In your case, because you want to constantly send data with your `UdpClient`, repeatedly instantiating and disposing the object (that is done by `using` statement), **might reduce the performance** (in your words hurts your performance :) ); So I prefer to define a non-local variable in my application, call it whenever I want and then `Dispose` it when no longer needed.

Comment: yes, I think this is a much better approach for this example, since the event will fire multiple times a second. Better to keep a single UdpClient instance open, and Dispose it when you finish recording